# How to convert all pdf files to text (within a folder) with one command?

Tags: pdf, text, convert, batch

I know that I can convert pdf files to text files one by one like this :

```
$ pdftotext filename.pdf
```

But is there a single command that would make that conversion without specifying separate file names so as to convert them all?

I see [here, on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pdftotext), that "Wildcards (*), for example $ pdftotext *pdf, for converting multiple files, cannot be used because pdftotext expects only one file name."

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The following will convert all files in the current directory:

```
for file in *.pdf; do pdftotext "$file" "$file.txt"; done
```

Comment: its only one command, it can be typed in one line in the terminal (its the pdftotext inside a for loop in a one-line-syntax, which is what the op asked for)

Comment: check out these links for more info of how the for loop works:
http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-for-loop/
http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/07/bash-for-loop-examples/

Comment: would this not cause issues with non-pdf files?

Comment: Wouldn't this produce files like "filename.pdf.txt"?

Comment: yes, if that's a problem, we could remove the .pdf extension using 'sed' or 'awk' but it would add complexity to the command

Comment: this solution has also the advantage of converting only the files in a directory at the level where it is fired and not downward onto the directory structure, into other directories and sub-directories

Comment: You can just `for file in *.pdf; do pdftotext "$file"; done` and it will replace `.pdf` with `.txt`. No need for `sed` or `awk`.

Answer (score 11):

```
ls *.pdf | xargs -n1 pdftotext
```

`xargs` is often a quick solution for running the same command multiple times with just a small change each time. The `-n1` option makes sure that only one pdf file is passed to pdftotext at a time.

Edit: If you're worried about spaces in filenames and such, you can use this alternative:

```
find . -name '*.pdf' -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 pdftotext
```

Comment: please see my answer: can that command be adapted so as to avoid the problem mentioned there? this doesn't mean that your solution is not good, on the contrary, it does something very specific that the other alternatives here do not. but i was just curious

Comment: Alternatively: `ls *.pdf | xargs -L1 -I% pdftotext % %.txt`

Answer (score 2):

write a bash script

```
for f in *.pdf; do
  pdftotext "$f"
done
```

or type it in a one-line command as follows:

`for f in *.pdf; do pdftotext "$f"; done`

I hope this helps. I do not have a large group of .pdfs to test this on, but I use this strategy to convert my .flac files to .ogg files.

Comment: can it be done by opening the terminal in that folder and running a command instead of inserting path manually?

Comment: couldn't you paste it here as such and insert it into your answer? that would be a good answer. i was not able to reach the good formula just by deleting a part of what you posted

Comment: the find and xargs I initially suggested did not work when I got a chance to test them.

Answer (score 1):

I have to thank first to [Sam](https://askubuntu.com/users/104480/sam) and to [Ryan Thompson](https://askubuntu.com/users/880/ryan-thompson) as well to all other answerers - for my answer here is nothing but a variation relating to the possibility of adding their solutions to Thunar's custom actions:

so, as any terminal command, a command to convert to text all pdf files within a folder   can be put in the list of custom actions in Thunar file  manager

[image]

[image]

[image]

The command there is `find . -name '*.pdf' -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 pdftotext`, (comming from [Ryan Thompson](https://askubuntu.com/users/880/ryan-thompson)) it is the one I prefer to use, but it has a nasty turn... see below...

[image]

[image]

...it is a funny command, to be used with care: it is made to convert to text all pdf within the folder where it is fired, so, if it is fired by mistake in the home folder, it will have some unwanted effects: all your pdfs will be converted to text!

(I tested it like this: created a folder called "test" on the desktop and in it a pdf file and a series of folders within folders (`/Desktop/test/a/b/c/e/f/g/h/i`) each containing the same pdf. Running that command in `/Desktop/test` has converted all pdfs down to that in "i" folder.)

(I would welcome comments on how to adjust this command so as to avoid that risk.)

Replacing that with the other one (`for file in *.pdf; do pdftotext "$file" "$file.txt"; done`) coming from  [Sam](https://askubuntu.com/users/104480/sam), the problem is avoided.

But in certain cases one might wish exactly what Ryan's solution does!

Comment: You can avoid the `find` command searching in subdirectories by using `-maxdepth 1`. Also, when putting it into Thunar's custom actions feature, you should probably replace `find .` with `find %F` to allow Thunar to properly pass the paths of the selected directories.

Answer (score 0):

```
for file in *.pdf; do pdftotext "$file" "$file.txt"; done
```

This one outputs *sample.pdf.txt*.

I tried using this one, as user2357111317 suggest and I also include *-layout* to preserve the layout of the text

```
for file in *.pdf; do pdftotext -layout "$file"; done
```